# What is "little" in Fermat's little theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, terminology, divisibility

Is there any logical reason or just introduced "little" in the name randomly.

Wikipedia says that it is called "little theorem" to distinguish it from Fermat's last theorem. Then why we just chose little and not any other term?

Comment: I guess that the little theorem has a more... little proof.

Comment: Some languages like German (in which much of the 19th-century research on the Last Theorem was written in) call the Last Theorem the _Great_ Theorem. Here the opposition is more clear.

Comment: Heh, what a strange and silly question!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I've never read or heard it called "Fermat's Great theorem". In German, I've only ever seen/heard it referred to as die Fermatsche Vermutung (Fermat's conjecture).

Comment: @DanielFischer The German Wikipedia page for the Last Theorem is titled _Großer Fermatscher Satz_.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Interesting. (I wouldn't know, 'cause I hardly ever look at the German wikipedia.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's called Fermat's Little Theorem since Euler later proved the more general theorem using his "Totient" function which then covered all integer modulus, not just the prime modulus.